# RegEx Get text between two strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following text:

```
{FFFFFF}Fe8uOywfW {EE9911}will
{FFFFFF}CV36LXRa {EE9911}will
{FFFFFF}lqtm {EE9911}will
{FFFFFF}2bCepDTJ {EE9911}will
{FFFFFF}cOu1bcaRT {EE9911}will
{FFFFFF}VbspL1XK {EE9911}will
{FFFFFF}your name {EE9911}will
{FFFFFF}NNXUELTq {EE9911}will
{FFFFFF}go to hill kide {EE9911}will
{FFFFFF}OJpbD2G1Y {EE9911}will
{FFFFFF}run noob {EE9911}will
{FFFFFF}fluffy {EE9911}will
```

I need to get all what's between "{FFFFFF}" and "{EE9911}will", so Fe8uOywfW, CV36LXRa, etc using Regular Expressions. I've tried many variants but none of them worked. (building with RegexMagic)

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: `I've tried many variants` such as....?

Comment: \{FFFFFF\}[^\n\r{]+\{EE9911\}will, for example

Comment: Did you also try the simplest one?! `{FFFFFF}([^\s]+)\s*?{EE9911}`

Comment: @revo yes it returns the same without "will" :(

Comment: It **matches** all desired occurrences and **captures** the text between. Matching differs from capturing. You now should work with captured groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more context about exactly what you do and don't want to match:

```
\{FFFFFF\}(.*)\{EE9911\}will
```

For example:

```
var s = @"{FFFFFF}Fe8uOywfW {EE9911}will
    {FFFFFF}CV36LXRa {EE9911}will
    {FFFFFF}lqtm {EE9911}will
    {FFFFFF}2bCepDTJ {EE9911}will
    {FFFFFF}cOu1bcaRT {EE9911}will
    {FFFFFF}VbspL1XK {EE9911}will
    {FFFFFF}your name {EE9911}will
    {FFFFFF}NNXUELTq {EE9911}will
    {FFFFFF}go to hill kide {EE9911}will
    {FFFFFF}OJpbD2G1Y {EE9911}will
    {FFFFFF}run noob {EE9911}will
    {FFFFFF}fluffy {EE9911}will";

    var r = new Regex(@"\{FFFFFF\}(.*)\{EE9911\}will");
    foreach (Match m in r.Matches(s)) {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);   // Note: you might want to add 
                                          // some error checking here
    }
```

Outputs:

```
Fe8uOywfW 
CV36LXRa 
lqtm 
2bCepDTJ 
cOu1bcaRT 
VbspL1XK 
your name 
NNXUELTq 
go to hill kide 
OJpbD2G1Y 
run noob 
fluffy
```

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/E6tB1x

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns the same text as the original one.

Comment: @user2729661: You need to look at the capture groups. That's what the brackets are for!

Comment: Is it vital to escape curly brackets?

Comment: @revo: In this particular case, actually no. But I tend to always escape special characters to avoid confusion.

Comment: You got your approach then!

Answer (score 0):

({F{6}})(.+)({EE9911}will)

Group them and use the second group

$2 will give the required string